# Avoid Overlapping log processing

Tags: logging

When scanning a series of files, for instance system logs, how can I avoid rescanning the same series of logs again? I am interested in doing what Splunk does any saving a logs in a database, however I cannot think of a way to update the database without placing some indicator in the file from a previous scan. Are there any techniques to this process or will I have to scan a file, find the last item from the previous scan, and start processing after that.

Answer (score 0):

1) Splunk does not use a database , it indexes information to compressed flat files on disk

2) If you are using Splunk to monitor your log files and directories of log files , then Splunk is intelligent enough to keep track of where it is in the monitoring so it won't re-index duplicate log events.